# How do I get passed this racing condition from Redux Toolkit?

Tags: javascript, react-redux, redux-toolkit

This is not happening in any other slice I created, and it's driving me nuts. I'm out of ideas to try. What I want is simple, pull the payload from my Slice so I can set it to my state and use it! But somehow I am not capturing it. I put a console.log on the Slice for the payload and I am successfully fetching See Pic Below
[image: Console log from mapSlice]

Now checkout this screenshot with the component on the screen. I noticed that I was getting an error for the 'country' being undefined in pullrank in line 285 which it doesnt mean the path in incorrect or that country doesnt exist, it just breaks because the whole data is empty. If I refresh it all comes up normally, so I commented out the part where I am setting setMinRange and setMaxRange and that's when I realize that `allmapdata` was setting up empty, Twice nontheless! And then once again with the data in it. Obviously a racing condition, the API is fetching before the data is called, so how do I delay this API call?

Here is my mapSlice

```
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import axios from "axios";

const KEY = process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY
const BASE_URL = process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL
const GLOBALVIEWS_API = `${BASE_URL}/countrymap`

const initialState = {
  mapdata:[],
  status: 'idle',  //'idle', 'loading', 'succeeded', 'failed'  
  error:null
}

export const fetchMapData = createAsyncThunk(
  'mapdata/fetchMapData', 
  async (id) => { 
    try {
      console.log("Firing Map reducer");
      const response = await axios.get(
        GLOBALVIEWS_API,
        {
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'X-API-KEY': KEY,
          },
          params: {
            titleId: id,
          }
        }
      )

      return response.data;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('API call error:', error.message);
    }
  }
)

const mapSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'mapdata',
  initialState,
  reducers:{
    fetchMap(state, action) {},
  },
  extraReducers(builder) {
    builder
      .addCase(fetchMapData.pending, (state, action) => {
        state.status = 'loading'
      })
      .addCase(fetchMapData.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.status = 'succeeded'
        const loadedMapData = action.payload.Item.season_met
        state.mapdata = loadedMapData
        console.log("loadedMapData: ", loadedMapData);
      })
      .addCase(fetchMapData.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.status = 'failed'
        state.error = action.error.message
      })
  }
})

// SELECTORS
// allMapData and fetchMap aren't both needed, I'm just trying different ways
export const allMapData = (state) => state.mapdata.mapdata;
export const {fetchMap} = mapSlice.actions;
export const getMapStatus = (state) => state.mapdata.status;
export const getMapError = (state) => state.mapdata.error;

export default mapSlice.reducer
```

Here's my component (reduced for brevity)

```
const MetricsCharts = ({selectedIndex}) => { 
  //STATES
  const [minrange, setMinRange] = useState();
  const [maxrange, setMaxRange] = useState(); 
  const [map, setMap] = useState([])
  
  
  const colorScale = scaleLog().domain([minrange, maxrange]).range(["#BAC7FF", "#6128BD"]); 
  const {id} = useParams();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  
  const allmapdata = useSelector(allMapData)
  const mapdata = useSelector(fetchMap)
  const mapStatus = useSelector(getMapStatus)
  const error = useSelector(getMapError)

  useEffect(() => {       
    if (mapStatus === 'idle') {
      dispatch(fetchMapData(id))
    }
    
    setMap(allmapdata)

    // const pullrank = allmapdata[selectedIndex].country.map(data => data.lifetime_viewing_subs)    
    // setMinRange(Math.min(...pullrank))
    // setMaxRange(Math.max(...pullrank))
    
    console.log("allmapdata: ", allmapdata); 
        
  }, [id, selectedIndex, dispatch, allmapdata, mapStatus, mapdata])


  let map_component;
  
  if (mapStatus === 'loading') {
    map_component = 
      <Box className="loading">
        <LoadingButton loading 
          loadingIndicator={
            <CircularProgress color="primary" size={50} />
          }>           
        </LoadingButton>
        <Typography variant='subtitle2'>Loading content, please wait...</Typography>
      </Box>
  } else if (mapStatus === 'succeeded') {
    map_component = 
    <>
      {map.length > 0 && //checking if something is in the state
        <Box sx={{mt:2}}>
          <ReactTooltip>{content}</ReactTooltip>
          <ComposableMap
            width={900}
            height={400}
            data-tip=""
            projectionConfig={{ rotate: [-10, 0, 0], scale:147 }}>
            <Sphere stroke="#000" strokeWidth={0.3} />
            <Graticule stroke="#000" strokeWidth={0.3} />              
            <Geographies geography={geoUrl}>
              {({ geographies }) => geographies.map((geo, index) => {
                const countries = map[selectedIndex].country.find( (s) =>  s.ISO3 === geo.properties.ISO_A3);  
                return (
                  <Fragment key={index}>
                    <Geography
                      key={geo.rsmKey}
                      geography={geo}
                      onMouseEnter={() => {
                        setContent(
                          countries 
                          ? `${geo.properties.NAME_LONG} — ${rounded(Math.round(countries.lifetime_viewing_subs))}` 
                          : ""
                        );
                      }}
                      fill={
                        countries 
                        ? colorScale(countries["lifetime_viewing_subs"]) 
                        : "#333"
                      } 
                    />
                  </Fragment>
                );                         
                  
                })
              }
            </Geographies>  
          </ComposableMap>
        </Box>
      }
    </>
  } else if (mapStatus === 'failed') {
    map_component = 
      <Box className="loading">
        <Typography variant="subtitle2">{error}</Typography>
      </Box>
  } 

  return (
    <div>
       {map_component}
    </div>  
  )
}

export default MetricsCharts
```

As you can see, I can't just give you a CODEPEN cause the map dependency is incredibly large and complex. I'm sorry about that. I do appreciate any help

[image]

Comment: if i understand your question correctly, you want to store the api payload or create a copy of payload once you store the payload in `state.mapData` and store it in `setMap`. If this is a case, then you can have a check in useEffect if `map` not set yet and `mapStatus === 'succeeded'` then set `allMapData` in `map` state. Also move `state.status==='succeeded'` after you store the payload in extraReducer

Comment: I van't check for map (the state) because it's not set yet. Until after the useEffect function has ran. That would just add to the race condition